# How do you make 4 2x2 buttons having the same dimensions

Tags: android, button

I want to create a group of 2by2 buttons aligned to each other like this:

A B

C D

each having the same width and height regardless of the length of their content.

I try using the following setup with nested LinearLayouts, it meets my requirement, however I have received a warning saying that nested layout_weight has great(exponential) impact on performance.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="aaa"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonC"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonD"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I wonder if there is a better way to do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for that.:) Couldn't imagine we could put a tablerow outside a TableLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout` with 2 `TableRows` and insert 2 `Buttons` in each `TableRow`.
Assign `width` and `height` accordingly to your needs.
Assign a `weight` of 1 to each item including the `TableRows` and you should be good to go.

**EDIT**: Ok after playing a bit around I found this was working good ;-)

This is basically a mix of your own layout and mine ;-)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd" />
    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is what I was originally doing, but after some testing, I found that the height of the two rows could be different if the content of the buttons on the first row is taller/shorter that those on the second row.

Comment: Yes I see - I'll do some more testing and hopefully get back to you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but you could use `button.getWidth()` to get the width of the 4 buttons. Find the max of the 4 and then set all the buttons to that width. If the content of the buttons are going to be dynamic.

Comment: I will try that, but having to config the layout in the code is the last thing I would want to do.

Comment: This would probably be your best option due to the wide range of devices.